# Count number of iterations in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

How to calculate how many items in a foreach?

I want to count total rows.

```
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
    $item[number];// if there are 15 $item[number] in this foreach, I want get the value : 15
}
```

Comment: Does every item has a *number*?

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is a php construct, and doesn't have any items - arrays do.
using [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)($array) returns the number of elements in it.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you just want to find out the number of elements in an array, use [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). Now, to answer your question...

> How to calculate how many items in a foreach?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
    $item[number];// if there are 15 $item[number] in this foreach, I want get the value : 15
    $i++;
}
```

If you only need the index inside the loop, you could use

```
foreach($Contents as $index=>$item) {
    // $index goes from 0 up to count($Contents) - 1
    // $item iterates over the elements
}
```

Comment: i just did `$index+1` for the row number, exactly what i need, thanks!

Answer (score 51):

You don't need to do it in the `foreach`.

Just use `count($Contents)`.

Comment: Count() works fine but for counting how many rows were supposed to be inserted or updated based on the query but suppose one or more failed for some reason? In that event, I would expect the count would be false.

Answer (score 22):

```
count($Contents);
```

or

```
sizeof($Contents);
```

Comment: Don't use `sizeof`, it's just an alias to the real thing and can cause confusion: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Answer (score 20):

```
foreach ($Contents as $index=>$item) {
  $item[$index];// if there are 15 $item[number] in this foreach, I want get the value : 15
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a few different ways you can tackle this one.

You can set a counter before the foreach() and then just iterate through which is the easiest approach.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
      $counter++;
       $item[number];// if there are 15 $item[number] in this foreach, I want get the value : 15
}
```

Comment: var in PHP is wrong. (this isn't a JavaScript question)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
          something 
          your code  ...
      $counter++;      
}
$total_count=$counter-1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `sizeof($Contents)` or `count($Contents)`

also this

```
$count = 0;
foreach($Contents as $items) {
  $count++;
  $items[number];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$Contents = array(
    array('number'=>1), 
    array('number'=>2), 
    array('number'=>4), 
    array('number'=>4), 
    array('number'=>4), 
    array('number'=>5)
);

$counts = array();

foreach ($Contents as $item) {
    if (!isset($counts[$item['number']])) {
        $counts[$item['number']] = 0;
    }
    $counts[$item['number']]++;
}

echo $counts[4]; // output 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{       
    if(!isset($counter))
    {
        $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

//Sorry if the code isn't shown correctly. :P

//I like this version more, because the counter variable is IN the foreach, and not above.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a counter with an initial value of `0`.

For every loop, increment the counter value by 1 using `$counter = 0;`

The final counter value returned by the loop will be the number of iterations of your for loop. Find the code below:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($Contents as $item) {
    $counter++;
    $item[number];// if there are 15 $item[number] in this foreach, I want get the value `: 15`
}
```

Try that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and explain a bit why it solves the issue and how. For more guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

```
    $index = 0;
    foreach( $array ?? [] as  $index=> $item  ) {
         $index++;

          $data[] = array(

                'id' =>$index

         );
           
        
    }
```