# Foreach loop add class depending on number

Tags: php, foreach

I have managed to find answers close to what I require but I am still having an issue. I have based my code on the answer at [Count number of iterations in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220546/count-number-of-iterations-in-a-foreach-loop).

Basically, I want to add a class to a list item which appears in a foreach loop. The class that I want to add is to be based on the count of the list item. For example I want the out put to look like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="item-1"></li>
  <li class="item-2"></li>
  <li class="item-3"></li>
<ul>
```

So far, my code looks like:

```
<ul>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <li class="item-<?php echo $count=>$photo[number]; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

The issue seems to be that I cannot use `<?php echo $count=>$photo[number]; ?>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `echo $photo[number];` only

Comment: `<?php echo $photo['number'];?>` not `<?php echo $count=>$photo[number]; ?>`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are adding classes with indexed names like that? What are you going to use them for? Both CSS and JS frameworks allow you to refer to elements by index without any classes at all.

Comment: use `print_r($gallery)` and see what result you find and post it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use

```
$count => $photo[number];
```

Particularly, since you are in a foreach loop, "$count =>" is not necessary.

Since you're not providing your $gallery array structure, I suppose that you want to print the index $i of the element $photo.

So... Hopefully this is what you want to do:

```
<ul>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <li class="item-<?php echo $photo[$i]; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

If you have, instead, an associative array and you want to print the 'number' key of each $photo element:

```
<ul>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
      <?php $i++; ?>
      <li class="item-<?php echo $photo['number']; ?>"></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But in such case the variable $i won't make any sense.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use <?php echo $photo[$i]; ?> or <?php echo $photo['number']; ?> then I just get a blank page.

Comment: Can you please provide us your $gallery array structure? if possible, use: print_r($gallery); before your foreach loop and post it!

Comment: The problem is, I am modifying someone else's code and I don's know where the array is :(

Comment: You don't need to know where the array is, just use print_r($gallery); and refresh the page! :) If it doesn't print it, you may have more errors in your code!

Comment: So sorry but where abouts do I put print_r($gallery); ?

Comment: Wherever you want, it would be better, however, to use print_r right before the foreach loop!

Answer (score 0):

I want just to explain some points here when looping:

```
<ul>
<?php $i = 0; ?> //No use
<?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
  <?php $i++; ?> //THIS , No use
  <li class="item-<?php echo $photo[number]; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

First, when using foreach function. You don't need to use incremental variables , it already loops all the values in your array. It's `foreach($array as $keys => $values)` you just need to echo `$key['mycolumn'] or $values`

Second is that just incase when you use incremental variable best practice is to put the incremental is before the loops end. **Reason** you might use the inappropriate index for that.

This should be likely correct:

```
<ul>
    <?php $i = 0; ?> // you can remove this
    <?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo): ?>
      <li class="item-<?php echo $photo[number]; ?>"></li>
        <?php $i++; ?> // increments here , you can remove this
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just get a blank page.

Comment: @DesignSubway, can you put your array values above. Thx I think I misunderstand your question.

Comment: The problem is, I am modifying someone else's code and I don's know where the array is :(

Comment: @DesignSubway, use print_r($gallery); then update the details in your question above.