# Inject css link to the head with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would you be able to inject a css link thats in the middle of the page to the head using javascript

```
<head>
  ... styles here
</head>
<body>
 code
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</body>
```

i need some sort of javascript to push the google fonts into head, what would be the easiest way?

Comment: What would be the point? If you can add JavaScript to the page, why can't you manually move the CSS link? No to mention the fact that by the time the JS has found the link, the link should have already been loaded.

Comment: i only have access to part of the code so not the head, also it was to try and solve another problem this font doesnt seem to work in firefox

Comment: Try giving this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6220566/3756866 - you could probably have it added after your <title>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('head').append("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
```

Try this and let me know if this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as ....

```
$("head").append($("link").clone());
```

You could make your selector more specific if you have other link elements

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do it like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('head').append("link");

</script>
```